# why would my javascript file not be loading?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a JS file into my website, I have placed the file into exactly the same folder as one that does load, but firebug does not show that it has loaded, and it's effects are not visible.

Why could this be?

Here is the code to load the script

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/page-customs/js/QES_form_edits.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/page-customs/js/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The first is not being loaded, the second is.

Here is the script itself:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("fieldset#keyword p.instruction").html("Search for a name or description of an activity, venue (e.g. Link Center) 
    or other keywords (e .g. coach)");


});
```

Jquery is loading fine.

Comment: how are you trying to load it?

Comment: Does the HTML output look correct? Does the URL have a leading slash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebug will not show a javascript file as loaded if the file will not run due to invalidation. Fix JS, fix problem.

Comment: This is exactly what my problem was, when re-using some code I forgot one of these: `});` and the file wouldn't be loaded. Everything else in that file was being ignored. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the file actually exists.  If you "view source", from the browser, you can hilite then right-click and copy the URL of the script.  Go back to the browser, open a new tab, and right-click->paste the URL into the address bar, press enter.  Does the script load in the browser window?  If not, check the capitalization and spelling.

You script tag looks correct, so check your underlying assumptions.

**EDIT**

OK, since the file exists, let's determine why it isn't loading.  You mentioned having Firebug, open that and switch to the 'Net' panel.  You should see a GET for the script in question, along with its status.  Is the status 200?  Click that row and check the headers, as well as the Response tab within the expanded row.  What do you see there?

Can you provide an example URL where this is occurring?

Comment: loads just fine using that method, and link appears in the head, but not on the list of loaded Js files in firebug

Comment: @Mild: what are the permissions on the 'bad' .js file? Could be the webserver doesn't have the rights to read it, which you'd see if you tried to access the .js direct via its url - permission denied

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

in your source

Comment: How is this useful? The OP clearly has a proper script tag, though with an unknown src path due to the php snippet in there. "You need to sharpen your pencil so you can sharpen your pencil" is not exactly useful advice.

Comment: an emphasis on the `</script>`, since most browser does not recognize the shortcut closing tag `/>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be anything from file permissions or a poorly formatted file. I would check either of those. Also, is there anything in the "Net" tab in firebug that looks like it's at least trying to download the file?

Answer (score 0):

An invalid html can also cause js files not to load. In my case I had this html inside a `<div>` in the main `<body>` tag:-

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <style type="text/css" style="display:none;">
```

All the content after this piece of code was not recognized properly by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did some changes which were not rendering correctly. So, I would recommend you to undo the changes that you have done (if any) and try.