# <head> does not load script when opening with browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to learn React, and my goal is render some results of Mocha tests using HTML instead of the console/stdout. But I am not very good with web development.

I have this code in an HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<script>


    var ContactItem = React.createClass({
        propTypes: {
            name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        },

        render: function() {
            return (
                    React.createElement('li', {className: 'Contact'},
                            React.createElement('h2', {className: 'Contact-name'}, this.props.name)
                    )
            )
        }
    });

    var element = React.createElement(ContactItem, {name: "James K Nelson"});



</script>

<div id="react-app"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

the React code is basically verbatim from online examples, and the CDN links should be loading the libraries correctly.

The problem I am having is that React is not defined in the script tags.

Is there any good reason why that should happen? One thing is that I am just running this file with Chrome and not serving the file with a webserver.

Comment: put your scripts at the bottom of your page but before the </body></html> tags

Answer (score 2):

"Firebug will not show a javascript file as loaded if the file will not run due to invalidation. Fix JS, fix problem."
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791435/why-would-my-javascript-file-not-be-loading)